# What are those petite animals that resemble the main cast?

Tags: the-idolmaster

What those petite animals that Ami and Mami find in the Puchimasu spinoff series? Why do they resemble the main cast?

[image: What are these things?!]

Comment: It's equivalent to asking why the author comes up with the idea for the manga (? I'm not sure if its original is manga)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translated from the [Puchimas anime website](http://puchimas.com/introduction/index.html):

> **Puchidols** are mysterious cute little living creatures that reside at 765 Productions. They're the kind of organism that shoots beams, warps around (I think this means like teleportation), digs holes, and heals others, but they are still quite mysterious. But don't you get the feeling that they resemble the idols of 765 Productions?

Well, that's the official explanation, but I don't think it actually answers your question. It even reiterates your question of "why do they look like the idols"...